# Allocate more RAM to QGIS in Windows 10?

Tags: qgis, windows

I have a fairly large project with many layers that I'm working on. Lately, it became unstable, and keeps on crashing with the "Exception: Bad allocation" error. I tried resizing the pagefile, and giving QGIS a higher priority in the task manager. And yet, when RAM usage hits roughly 4 GB (upon loading the project), the error message pops up, rendering my project unusable. Are there any (hidden?) settings in QGIS to allocate more RAM, or maybe just stop loading layers once the threshold is hit?

E: Newest QGIS Version, 3.28; however I had the same problem in 3.24

Comment: You say "lately it became unstable...", so it _was_ loading up your project no problem? Would suggest something else like a windows update or some new application?

Comment: How much physical RAM is available? Windows reserves 4GB just for the operating system.

Comment: In addition to the prior comments, if you start your project after a complete reboot (shift + restart) with no other programs running, do you still get the error?  Can you run it on another machine to see if the same thing happens?  Here's some things I typically try when I have unexpected errors because they are easy and general: check validity of your layers, turn off any unusual plugins, save project to a copy and open the copy, and lastly rename the user data folder (so I can rename back if the change doesn't fix things) at C:\Users\your user name here\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3

Comment: @Hornbydd no update or new application; it did run until some point, when the exceptions started coming, and then rapidly "deteriorated"

Comment: @Mapperz 32 gig ram on the machine, max. 40% used

Comment: @John Yes, same error on "fresh" started PC. Same happens on other machines (tho it's a bit hard to verify, since the other machines available to me only have 8 gig ram). Thanks for the tips tho!